# Extending Bootstrap Dropdown / Usage of super in Coffee Script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I am trying to extend the Bootstrap Dropdown. I'm using the same method I used when extending the Bootstrap Modal but somehow on Dropdown it doesn't seem to work. I read throught the BS code but couldn't spot any obvious difference between those two.

```
_tgl = $.fn.dropdown.Constructor::toggle
$.fn.dropdown.Constructor::toggle = ->
  alert('foo')
  _tgl.apply(this, arguments)

_show = $.fn.modal.Constructor::show
$.fn.modal.Constructor::show = ->
  alert('bar')
  _show.apply(this, arguments)
```

The Code below works fine, upon opening a Modal I get the alert, on toggling the dropdown however nothing happens. If I insert an alert into the base toggle of BS Dropdown the alert pops us, thus the base method gets called, skipping my overrides... Any thoughts?

The second questions here is why doesn't super work here? E.g:

```
$.fn.dropdown.Constructor::toggle = ->
  alert('foo')
  super
```

The documentation as far as I understood it stated, that super would call the parent method, but it leads to compiling errors 'cannot call super outside of an instance method'. Does that mean I cannot use super outside of a class context even though I am overriding a class method?

PS: Here is the compiled JS code for the first example, for people not familiar with coffeescript:

```
  _tgl = $.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.toggle;

  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.toggle = function() {
    alert('foo');
    _tgl.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  _show = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.show;

  $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.show = function() {
    alert('foo');
    _show.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Comment: CoffeeScript's super uses `Constructor.__super__` which is undefined here.

Comment: `C::m = -> super` relies on `C.__super__` - just look at the compiled js

Comment: but `Blah.__super__` being undefined is a runtime error

Comment: So super not working is irrelevant to super not working ? Interesting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26403/discussion-between-user1737909-and-mu-is-too-short)